# How do I correct this regular expression and function in order to verify the correctness of a pandas column value pattern?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, validation

I would like to check that the the strings in my pandas column follow a specific pattern. I want to do so with a function check_pattern and a regular expression. The data should consist only out of digits except that there is a dash after the first two digits. A correct value would be 08-15643. Wrong values could for example be 07-456d, 04-47897-1, 084564, etc.)

Please take a look at the data and my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(str_list)
str_list = ['19-123', '08-156445787', '08-156468787-1']
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: "Strings" }, inplace = True)

def check_pattern(Strings):
    is_correct_pattern = False
    pattern = re.compile("^[0-9]{2}'-'[0-9]")
    if pattern.match(Strings) == True:
        is_correct_pattern = True
   return is_correct_pattern

df['Correct_pattern'] = df['Strings'].apply(lambda x: check_pattern(x))
```

My output should be the original dataframe df with an additional column Correct_Pattern. With the data df given, the result should be True, True, False for that column. If you have another idea for solving this I am also interested :)

Comment: Try `df['Correct_pattern'] = df['Strings'].str.match(r'^\d{2}-\d+$')`

Comment: yes, that's great. Except I want to keep record of the once that were False as well. I want to take a look at them. This expression only leaves me with the correct cases.

Comment: I tested the code and, with your input data, I get both True and False results.

Comment: Ok something went wrong. When I cleared my outputs and ran it again it worked. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`Series.str.match` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) to see if the pattern matches the string:

```
df['Correct_pattern'] = df['Strings'].str.match(r'^\d{2}-\d+$')
```

The `^\d{2}-\d+$` pattern matches the start of string (`^`, note that it is redundant with `re.match` but it is best to keep the anchor explicitly), then 2 digits, `-` and then `\d+` matches any 1+ digits and then asserts the position at the end of the string with the `$` anchor.

With `str_list = ['19-123', '08-156445787', '08-156468787-1']` as input, the output is:

```
>>> df
          Strings  Correct_pattern
0          19-123             True
1    08-156445787             True
2  08-156468787-1            False
```